# What does the title of Cowboy Bebop's eighth episode—"Waltz for Venus"—mean?

Tags: cowboy-bebop

I think you can have two (or possibly more) interpretations for this. One being a dance or music; the other being to accomplish something with little to no effort. Are these two interpretations correct or is it just the former that's correct?

Comment: As a note, I did recommend this question be asked here. It was originally asked (without context) on [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/265125/can-you-interpret-waltz-for-venus-differently). I've tried to cover the definitions in my answer over there but thought you all might have more insight into the specific episode, as I can't remember it very well.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a source that explicitly stated the meaning to the name of the episode. I agree with your interpretations with both of them fitting moments in the episode. So let's break down the episode:

**"[*Waltz for Venus*](http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/Waltz_For_Venus)"**

Venus is the setting for most of this episode so that fits just fine, the challenge is what the waltz stands for as. Stated on Merriam Webster the word **[*Waltz*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/waltz)** can be a dance/music with a time signature of 3/4. This particular definition doesn't seem to have any real relevance to the episode, but if we take the whole timeframe in which ***[Rocco Bonnaro](http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/Rocco_Bonnaro)*** is eluding [***Piccaro Calvino***](http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/Piccaro_Calvino) this could be considered a "dance".

The reason I say this because [***dance***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dance) as a verb can mean to move quickly or nimbly. This is why sometimes in sports, for example American football, sometimes sports announcers will say a player "danced around the defense", meaning they eluded the defense. So I don't think it is that much a stretch to say Rocco was "dancing" away from Piccaro.

Another reference from the episode that can be used is when ***[Spike](http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/Spike_Spiegel)*** and ***[Faye](http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/Faye_Valentine)*** take a commercial shuttle into Venus. They are doing this to catch some hijackers and defeat them very easily. This ties into the other definition of waltz being used as a verb and means to "to succeed at something easily".

Now this is in no way 100% the reason as to why the episode is titled this way but merely an interpretation as to why it could be.

Comment: "The Singing Sea," the song played by the music box, is in a compound meter. Without seeing the sheet music, my guess is 6/8 instead of 3/4. So, it's not really waltz music, but maybe the writers were just looking for another genre of music to use for an episode title.

Comment: @PaulRowe I looked up a score of "The Sining Sea" and its time signature is indeed  6/8