# Are all Cowboy Bebop's episodes named after songs?

Tags: cowboy-bebop

I noticed that some episodes are named after existing songs.

As an example, the [fourteenth episode](http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/Bohemian_Rhapsody) name is "*Bohemian Rhapsody*",  which is a famous song from the music band Queen

Are all Cowboy Bebop's episodes named after existing songs?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Not all episodes are named after songs but most of them are and they are all named after cultural references.

---

1 - [Asteroid Blues](http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/Asteroid_Blues)

> [The blues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blues) is a well known music genre

2 - [Stray Dog Strut](http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/Stray_Dog_Strut)

> [Stray Cat Strut](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4oQPn0rvXtE) is one of the most famous songs of the band [Stray Cats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stray_Cats)

3 - [Honky Tonk Women](http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/Honky_Tonk_Women)

> [Honky Tonk Women](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DXqQh7Y30eg) is a song composed by the [Rolling Stones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rolling_Stones)

4 - [Gateway Shuffle](http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/Gateway_Shuffle)

> [The Shuffle or Melbourne Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melbourne_Shuffle) is a rave and club dance

5 - [Ballad of Fallen Angels](http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/Ballad_of_Fallen_Angels)

> [Fallen Angels](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LVEcIOwHf2k) is a song composed by the band [Aerosmith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerosmith)

6 - [Sympathy for the Devil](http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/Sympathy_For_The_Devil)

> [Sympathy for the Devil](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZRXGsPBUV5g) is a song made by the [Rolling Stones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rolling_Stones)

7 - [Heavy Metal Queen](http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/Heavy_Metal_Queen)

> [Heavy Metal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_metal_music) is a rock/metal music genre

8 - [Waltz for Venus](http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/Waltz_For_Venus)

> - Waltz is both a [music genre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waltz_%28music%29) and a [dance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waltz). For more, see [this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/23838/cowboy-bebop-episode-title-waltz-for-venus-what-does-it-mean)
> - [Waltz for Debbie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dH3GSrCmzC8) is both a [song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waltz_for_Debby_%28song%29) and an [album](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waltz_for_Debby_%281962_album%29) composed by [Bill Evans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Evans)

9 - [Jamming with Edward](http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/Jamming_With_Edward)

> Jamming with Edward is an album released in 1972 by the [Rolling Stones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rolling_Stones)

10 - [Ganymede Elegy](http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/Ganymede_Elegy)

> - [Elegy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elegy_%28band%29) is a Dutch Power Metal band.
> - An [elegy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elegy) is also a type poem

11 - [Toy in the Attic](http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/Toys_In_The_Attic)

> Toys in the Attic is both a [song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7X8OQ7BEqM) and an [album](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toys_in_the_Attic_%28album%29) composed by the band [Aerosmith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerosmith)

12 & 13 - [Jupiter Jazz](http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/Jupiter_Jazz_%28Part_1%29)

> [Jazz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jazz) is a genre of music

14 - [Bohemian Rhapsody](http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/Bohemian_Rhapsody)

> [Bohemian Rhapsody](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJ9rUzIMcZQ) is a song composed by [Queen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_%28band%29).

15 - [My Funny Valentine](http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/My_Funny_Valentine)

> There are multiple possible references.
>
> - The [album](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Funny_Valentine_%28album%29) by Miles Davis
> - The [music](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Are-c0BLyIg) by [Frank Sinatra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Sinatra)
> - [My Bloody Valentine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Bloody_Valentine_%28band%29) is an alternative rock band

16 - [Black Dog Serenade](http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Dog_Serenade)

> [Black Dog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jtN8oBjMr_E) is a song composed by the band [Led Zeppelin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Led_Zeppelin). A serenade is a type of song.

17 - [Mushroom Samba](http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/Mushroom_Samba)

> [Samba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba) is a Brazilian song and dance genre

18 - [Speak Like a Child](http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/Speak_Like_A_Child)

> [Speak Like a Child](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speak_Like_a_Child_%28album%29) is an album made by [Herbie Hancock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbie_Hancock)

19 - [Wild Horses](http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/Wild_Horses)

> [Wild horses](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SQTHB4jM-KQ) is a song composed by the [Rolling Stones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rolling_Stones)

20 - [Pierrot Le Fou](http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/Pierrot_Le_Fou)

> [Pierrot Le Fou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierrot_le_Fou) is a 1965 postmodern film directed by the French and Swiss filmmaker Jean-Luc Godard, who was one of the founding members of the French New Wave in cinema.

21 - [Boogie Woogie Feng Shui](http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/Boogie_Woogie_Feng_Shui)

> [Boogie Woogie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boogie-woogie) is a musical genre

22 - [Cowboy Funk](http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/Cowboy_Funk)

> [Funk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funk) is a genre of music

23 - [Brain Scratch](http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/Brain_Scratch)

> Evil **Brain** Rejector is a song composed by [Lee **"Scratch"** Perry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lee_%22Scratch%22_Perry) (album [Jamaican E.T.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamaican_E.T.))

24 - [Hard Luck Woman](http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/Hard_Luck_Woman)

> [Hard Luck Woman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GUFuJQATLZA) is a song composed by the band [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiss_%28band%29)

25 & 26 - [The Real Folk Blues](http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/The_Real_Folk_Blues_Part_1)

> [The Real Folk Blues](http://www.allmusic.com/album/the-real-folk-blues-mw0000200016) is a song composed by [John Lee Hooker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Lee_Hooker)

Comment: Nice answer, my friend.  :)

Comment: If we add the movie into this situation Knockin' On Heaven's Door is a song by Guns N' Roses